# Does NCache's write-behind functionality do coalescing/combining?

Tags: ncache

I.e. if the application makes multiple writes to the same object, will NCache make only one update to the datasource? (using only the latest values?)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use item version to identify if you need to update the item or not, using caching as the first level of identification, one can verify that does the item needs to be updated or not

[Cache Item Version](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help-4-1/cache-item-version.html?mw=MjQw&st=MQ==&sct=MA==&ms=CQABAAAgAAAAAEIgMBA=)

Edit: In short; no it will not, it's your responsibility

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not combine operations. If you do multiple updates of same object, ncache will make same number of updates to the datasource. Thats what I have experienced.